# ListView always on top

Tags: android, listview

I use below code to update listview.

```
setListAdapter(MyAdapter);
MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
getListView().setEmptyView(empty);
```

But each time update, the list always show top one.
I want to let it only update data, but not focus on top.
How to do it?

Comment: Not enough information. Understand how views are stacked based on a root layout and then update your question as of now.. this is **NOT** enough information to diagnose your issue.

Comment: If you want to update listview MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is enough. Why do you call, setListAdapter(MyAdapter);--  this might be the reason why your listview gets on top.

Comment: Do you mean that the list view scrolls to the top after your update, instead of keeping its scroll position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `listview.setSelection(your_collection.size());`. This will make the last item in the ListView as selected when you refresh the ListView. Also call this after refereshing the ListView.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ArrayAdapter backed by an ArrayList. To change the data, just update the data in the list and call

MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Although you can call notifyDataSetChanged() on SimpleAdapter too.